# Is it possible to use an svg image as a sprite image in background?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-sprites

Is it possible to use a svg image as a sprite image in background, as shown in the below code. The below code works with a png sprite image but would want to use it with an svg image. Anybody has inputs as to how we go about it and if will it support on different browsers?

Example :

```
.background-star {
  background: transparent url(../../../images/web/icons/sprite1.svg) no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.background-star.position-1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.background-star.position-2 {
    background-position: 20px 0;
}
.background-star.position-3 {
    background-position: 40px 0;
}

etc so, that different parts of the image can be accessed?
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing with your svg image?

Comment: Hey @RobertLongson, just wanted to know if it will work, as have not used an svg image as a sprite image before.

Comment: Try it and see. svg images are mostly interchangeable with raster images

Comment: you will probably need to define the background-size. We need to see your SVG to know the issue